# Node version 8 and global dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

I recently upgraded to Node version 8.11.1 on Windows. I do not see the "npm" directory which generally was seen under 
C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming

So, essentially, I am trying to understand under which location do global packages get installed with Node v8 & above
e.g. if I run
npm install -g some-dependency

Where can I find "some-dependency" with Node v8 ? Did something change ?

Comment: Did you check this page ? https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders

Comment: Yes, but does not have much info & on Windows platform